# Magento table rate shipping method only for price

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I am curently using Magento 1.9.1 and i want to set up a table rate for shipping.
In the shipping methods i can see only 3 conditions:

`Weight vs. Destination`
`Price vs Destination` 
and `# of Items vs. Destination`

My questions is - How i make it count only the price. They are delivered all from england but there is only change of the shipping price on different purchase price.

**For example, for purchases:**

for store purchases for or less 25 pounds the Shipping fee is  3 pounds.

for store purchases for 50 pounds the Shipping fee is  5 pounds.

for store purchases for 75 pounds the Shipping fee is  7 pounds.

for store purchases for 100 pounds the Shipping fee is  9 pounds.

for store purchases for 150 pounds the Shipping fee is  12 pounds.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just do it Price vs Destination and only use table rates as you normally would. If necessary restrict countries that can be shipped to in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use Amasty Table Rate Shipping extension.